# hide and show input on click javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am trying to start with my p tag hidden, and then on click display the input field on screen. I have this right now:

```
<label for="check-1">Small</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="small" value="small" onclick="sFunction()">

    <script>
      function sFunction() {
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = '<label for="check-1">SMALL Price ($).   </label><input type="text" name="s" id="small">';
      }
    </script>
    <p id="s"></p>
```

however, I obviously can't close it, im not really sure how to hide it again on checkbox click. so right now it starts hidden, and then on click, shows, then I need it to hide if I click it again. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more possible solution to modify to your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<title> Test Page </title>
<style>
 .hide { display: none; }
</style>
</head><body>

<label for="check-1">Small</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" onclick="sFunction()">
<span id="smallPrice" class="hide" >Price $ <input type="text" id="small"></span>

<script>
function sFunction() {
  document.getElementById("smallPrice").classList.toggle('hide');
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

You can even re-arrange the display to remove the checkbox:

```
<label for="check-1">Small</label>
<span id="smallPrice" class="hide" >
<input type="checkbox" id="check-1" onclick="sFunction()">
Price $ <input type="text" id="small"></span>
```

One more option that doesn't use JS at all -- CSS only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<title> Toggle input element </title>

<style>
 label { font-size: 1.5em; color: red; }
 label:hover { cursor: pointer; }
 .toggle + label + span{ display:none; }
 .toggle:checked + label + span{ display:inline-block; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" class="toggle" hidden="">
<label for="toggle1">Small</label>
<span> Price $ <input type="text" id="small"></span>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like this :

- you set a `visibility style` to your `p tag`
- on your onclick function you check if the visibility style on your `p tag` if it is hidden, `if yes` you make it `visible`, `if no` you make it `hidden`

  ```
   <label for="check-1">Small</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="small" value="small" onclick="sFunction()">

    <script>
      function sFunction() {
        if ("hidden" == document.getElementById("s").style.visibility) {
          document.getElementById("s").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("s").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
      }
    </script>
    <p id="s" style="visibility:hidden">
       <label for="check-1">SMALL Price ($).</label><input type="text" name="s" id="small">
    </p>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use the classlist.toggle method of the object, this way you can implement utilitary css classes like the one in the example and adapt it to your own needs, also making it reusable.

```js
let toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');
console.log(toggler);
toggler.onclick = function(){
  let paragraph = document.getElementById('theParagraph');
  paragraph.classList.toggle("hidden");
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggler">toggle it</button>
<p id="theParagraph" class="hidden">the paragraph</p>
```

I'd recommend you to take a look at the events that can be used here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#most_common_categories